# Page flip effect on button press in html5

Tags: html, canvas

I'm looking at this:

http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/create-page-flip-effect-html5-canvas

However, I have one problem with that - I need to be able to click on the pages, even the edges, without triggering the page turn. I want the pages to turn when a button outside of the canvas is pressed. Is this possible using the base they provided, or do I need to go an entirely different direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that can be done.

From what i can see, you need a click event that doesnt trigger the page drag. You need to assign a flag for this.

Let **Drag** = *mouse drag/mouse move*, **down** = *mouse down*, **release** = *mouse release* events respectively.
Initialize your flag variable as false. When a drag event is encountered it becomes true. Otherwise it remains false. As long as it is false when the mouse release event occurs it can be treated as a click. Thats the basic principle behind using `mousedown` and `mouseup` as a click event.

You will have to use [e.srcElement](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html) or [e.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.target) to give you the element your cursor is currently positioned over inorder to trigger click functions relative to that element.

If you want a more detailed explanation on the page flip technique then check [this](http://blogs.cynergysystems.com/2009/11/13/the-secret-behind-the-page-flip-technique/) out. Helped me lot.

Comment: I don't want the turning to trigger at all from inside the canvas, only from a button outside.

Comment: Yes thats my point. Your mousedown and mouseup events(without mousemove event) become the click event. Once you've eliminated the drag you can use your click events to do your bidding without being interfered by the pageTurn that happens in drag and ofcourse u need to cancel the intial offsets in mousedown which starts curling the page.

Comment: cynergysystems link has gotten moldy.

Comment: @MrBoJangles, Will try to get a new one.